# Interpreter for Planner programming lanuage

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm looking for an interpreter/compiler of [Planner language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planner_%28programming_language%29) for Windows or Linux. I tried to search, but didn't find anything. Are there any?

Comment: I don't know the details of `Planner` itself but you can implement a planner in Prolog. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515519/1243762) is a basic example in Prolog. There are many improvements to this that can be found in various books such as the one by Luger. If you keep going down this path you might find that [Constraint Satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) solves your problem.