# Similar like world blocks in prolog with new rules

Tags: prolog, planning

I will go on a trip and take my pets, I have 3 animals (dog, cat, rat), but they don't get along very well.
I can only take 1 animal at a time, but I can't leave the dog with the cat or the cat with the hamster alone because they would literally eat each other, I am looking for Prolog to find my result of valid transitions to get to my new house with my 3 animals.
I took Bratko's world of blocks, since each block I can interpret as 1 animal, and the 3 lists that the original problem raises I can see as `[[old house], [who do I take?], [new house]]`, it would only be necessary to add the rules that animals should not be together and that the goal ends in the third list. an example of what I'm looking for is the following...

-? solucion4([[dog,cat,rat],[],[]],X).

```
X = [[dog,cat,rat],[],[]], %%%this is my start
       [[dog,rat],[cat],[]],
       [[dog],[rat],[cat]],
       [[dog],[cat],[rat]],
       [[cat],[dog],[rat]],
      [[],[cat],[rat,dog]],
      [[],[],[rat,dog,cat]], %%% this is my goal
```

I don't care about the order of list 3 `[[], [], [new house]]`, I care about the transition of animals between each list, so that they don't fight when I leave them alone.

in others words...

I am a beginner in programming with prolog, I had a question.
From the block world in Bratko's book, I need to arrange the "blocks" **DOG CAT RAT**, I just **can't put CAT with/over RAT** or vice versa, and **DOG with/over CAT**, or vice versa, and I can only pass block by block, one by one.
I have 3 places, the result of the "ordered" list should be in place 3, something like this: R = (previously there are all the changes you made to get to this) ... [[ ], [ ], [cat, rat, dog]].

This is my code...

```
s(Pilas, [Pila1, [Tope1|Pila2] | OtrasPilas ]) :-
    quitar([Tope1|Pila1], Pilas, Pilas1),
    quitar(Pila2, Pilas1, OtrasPilas).

quitar(X, [X|Ys], Ys).
quitar(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Ys1]) :-
    quitar(X,Ys,Ys1).

meta(Estado) :-
    member([rat,dog,cat],Estado). % Here I need any order but in list 3
```

and my restrictions are...

```
invalido(dog,cat).
invalido(cat,dog).
invalido(cat,rat).
invalido(rat,cat).

verifica(Animal,NO_Llevar):-
  invalido(Animal,Este_no),
  NO_Llevar = Este_no.
```

and my algorithm of search

```
camino(Nodo,Nodo,[Nodo]).
camino(PrimerNodo,UltimoNodo,[UltimoNodo|Camino]) :-
    camino(PrimerNodo,MenosElUltimo,Camino),
    s(MenosElUltimo,UltimoNodo),
    \+ member(UltimoNodo,Camino).

solucion4(NodoInicial,Sol) :-
    camino(NodoInicial,NodoMeta,Sol),
    meta(NodoMeta).
```

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog planning using retract and assert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55512086/1243762)

Comment: You should change `[[ ], [ ], [Cat, Rat, Dog]]` to `[[ ], [ ], [cat, rat, dog]]` as someone might think you are trying your code with variables and not values.

Comment: Where is the predicate `verifica/2` used? You show the code but I don't see a call to it. Did you give us all of the code?

Comment: Can you give a description of how your code is suppose to work. I have no idea what `invalido(dog,cat).` means. Does it mean a dog can not be next to a cat? Does it mean a dog and cat can not be on top of each other?

Comment: As I often tell others, if the [duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) doesn't know it, then I don't know it.

Comment: You're right, I already changed the values [dog,cat,rat], sorry for that.

Comment: "verifica / 2" is to see which animals can be together or not, in recursion with "invalido", that predicate I try to enter my code, and recursively verify the lists of the combinations that it has made, thus avoiding having together the animals that do not take each other, moving them to another list (avoid a fight between the animals).

Comment: What I am trying to say is that invalido are the movements that I cannot perform within the lists and verifica that the animal would be with the which is not carried, for example  -? verifica(Dog, X). X = cat.

Comment: Thanks for more info, but I still don't have a clear picture in my mind. If you could take the time to draw pictures and post them into the question it would help.

Comment: Of course, wait ...

Comment: thanks for your interest Guy Coder