# Program decomposition and lazy_findall

Tags: prolog

I like the idea of `lazy_findall` as it helps me with keeping *predicates separated* and hence program *decomposition*.

What are the cons of using `lazy_findall` and are there alternatives?

---

Below is my "coroutine" version of the branch and bound problem.

It starts with the problem setup:

```
domain([[a1, a2, a3], 
        [b1, b2, b3, b4],
        [c1, c2]]).

price(a1, 1900).
price(a2,  750).
price(a3,  900).
price(b1,  300).
price(b2,  500).
price(b3,  450).
price(b4,  600).
price(c1,  700).
price(c2,  850).

incompatible(a2, c1).
incompatible(b2, c2).
incompatible(b3, c2).
incompatible(a2, b4).
incompatible(a1, b3).
incompatible(a3, b3).
```

Derived predicates:

```
all_compatible(_, []).
all_compatible(X, [Y|_]) :- incompatible(X, Y), !, fail.
all_compatible(X, [_|T]) :- all_compatible(X, T).

list_price(A, Threshold, P) :- list_price(A, Threshold, 0, P).
list_price([], _, P, P).
list_price([H|T], Threshold, P0, P) :-
    price(H, P1),
    P2 is P0 + P1,
    P2 =< Threshold,
    list_price(T, Threshold, P2, P).

path([], []).
path([H|T], [I|Q]) :-
    member(I, H),
    path(T, Q),
    all_compatible(I, Q).
```

The actual logic:

```
solution([], Paths, Paths, Value, Value).
solution([C|D], Paths0, Paths, Value0, Value) :-
    (   list_price(C, Value0, V)
    ->  (   V < Value0
        ->  solution(D, [C], Paths, V, Value)
        ;   solution(D, [C|Paths0], Paths, Value0, Value)
        )
    ;   solution(D, Paths0, Paths, Value0, Value)   
    ).
```

The glue

```
solution(Paths, Value) :-
    domain(D),
    lazy_findall(P, path(D, P), Paths0),
    solution(Paths0, [], Paths, 5000, Value).
```

---

Here is an alternative no-lazy-findall solution by @gusbro: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68415760/1646086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `lazy_findall` but I observe two "drawbacks" with the presented approach:

1. The code is not as decoupled as one might want, because there is still a mix of "declarative" and "procedural" code in the same predicate. I am putting quotes around the terms because they can mean a lot of things but here I see that `path/2` is concerned with both generating paths AND ensuring that they are valid. Similarly `solution/5` (or rather `list_price/3-4`) is concerned with both computing the cost of paths and eliminating too costly ones with respect to some operational bound.
2. The "bounding" test only happens on complete paths. This means that in practice all paths are generated and verified in order to find the shortest one. It does not matter for such a small problem but might be important for larger instances. Ideally, one might want to detect for instance that the partial path [a1,?,?] will never bring a solution less than `2900` without trying all values for `b` and `c`.

My suggestion is to instead use clpfd (or clpz, depending on your system) to solve both issues. With clpfd, one can first state the problem without concern for how to solve it, then call a predefined predicate (like `labeling/2`) to solve the problem in a (hopefully) clever way.

Here is an example of code that starts from the same "setup" predicates as in the question.

```
state(Xs,Total):-
    domain(Ds),
    init_vars(Ds,Xs,Total),
    post_comp(Ds,Xs).


init_vars([],[],0).
init_vars([D|Ds],[X|Xs],Total):-
    prices(D,P),
    length(D,N),
    X in 1..N,
    element(X, P, C),
    Total #= C + Total0,
    init_vars(Ds,Xs,Total0).

prices([],[]).
prices([V|Vs],[P|Ps]):-
    price(V,P),
    prices(Vs,Ps).

post_comp([],[]).
post_comp([D|Ds],[X|Xs]):-
    post_comp0(Ds,D,Xs,X),
    post_comp(Ds,Xs).

post_comp0([],_,[],_).
post_comp0([D2|Ds],D1,[X2|Xs],X1):-
    post_comp1(D1,1,D2,X1,X2),
    post_comp0(Ds,D1,Xs,X1).    

post_comp1([],_,_,_,_).
post_comp1([V1|Vs1],N,Vs2,X1,X2):-
    post_comp2(Vs2,1,V1,N,X2,X1),
    N1 is N+1, 
    post_comp1(Vs1,N1,Vs2,X1,X2).

post_comp2([],_,_,_,_,_).
post_comp2([V2|Vs2],N2,V1,N1,X2,X1):-
    post_comp3(V2,N2,X2,V1,N1,X1),
    N3 is N2 + 1,
    post_comp2(Vs2,N3,V1,N1,X2,X1).

post_comp3(V2,N2,X2,V1,N1,X1) :-
    (  ( incompatible(V2,V1) 
       ; incompatible(V1,V2) 
       )
    -> X2 #\= N2 #\/ X1 #\= N1
    ;  true
    ).
```

Note that the code is relatively straightforward, except for the (quadruple) loop to post the incompatibility constraints. This is due to the way I wanted to reuse the predicates in the question. In practice, one might want to change the way the data is presented.

The problem can then be solved with the following query (in SWI-prolog):

```
?- state(Xs, T), labeling([min(T)], Xs).
T = 1900, Xs = [2, 1, 2] ?
```

In SICStus prolog, one can write instead:

```
?- state(Xs, T), minimize(labeling([], Xs), T).
Xs = [2,1,2], T = 1900 ?
```

Another short predicate could then transform back the `[2,1,2]` list into `[a2,b1,c2]` if that format was expected.

Comment: I am still new to Prolog, but I thought my `list_price` already cuts off early if the price accumulator goes above the threshold. More importantly, the case with `path` is exactly what I meant with decomposition. The compatibility question is separated from the `price < threshold` question. Maybe both can be formulated in terms of constraints, but traversing them in two recursive predicates carrying two separate sets of "state variables" still seems like a decomposition to me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to say that the code in the question was badly decomposed or anything (hence the quote marks around drawbacks) but I misread the question being also about feedback regarding decomposition in your code as well and I gave some suggestions.

Comment: When it comes to early cut off, there are (at least) two distinct places where you may want to cut early in some way. In your code, you indeed cut early the price computation inside `list_price`, but this is for each complete path in isolation. What I was suggesting was to cut early the path generation based on partial paths (i.e. containing only 1 or 2 elements of the 3 elements in this case). This is actually done in the code by @gusbro that you refer to, and is possible there because path creation and pricing are done together, but would be much more difficult in your approach.